# Nifi GenerateTableFetch gives error when partition size is set to zero

Tags: java, apache, apache-nifi

While setting partitionSize=0 so as to fetch all the rows in the given table for GenerateTableFetch Processor in Nifi, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4]
>   o.a.n.p.standard.GenerateTableFetch
>   GenerateTableFetch[id=d0932834-015d-1000-8224-c230630b6fa6]
>   GenerateTableFetch[id=d0932834-015d-1000-8224-c230630b6fa6] failed to
>   process session due to java.lang.NullPointerException: {}
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch.onTrigger(GenerateTableFetch.java:300)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1120)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

When I give partitionSize>0 it works. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a bug in the processor code for the case where Partition Size is 0.

I have created this JIRA for it: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4286

Comment: Will migrating to a newer version solve the problem?

Comment: The latest code still has the problem so it would still be an issue in the last release (1.3.0). Maybe as a work-around you could just use ExecuteSQL to select the whole table?